# Insert values into second table with foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in one database.

**Table 1**

- name (primary)
- age
- address

**Table 2**

- name (foreign key )
- model
- year
- color

  I have already insert values to table 1 but i want to insert values to table 2
  where t2.name=t1.name. Can you help me?
  I've tried this

> ```
> insert into table2(name,model,year,color) SELECT name FROM table1 VALUES('"+
>                 name+"'," + model + "','" + year + "','" + color + "') ;
> ```

But it didn't work!
I have no errors but the table is empty!

Comment: You have to clarify the logic to fill table2

Comment: the model,year,color should insert into row of table2 with name="John"